# How do you test the read-side processor in Lagom?

Tags: scala, testing, lagom

I have a read-side that is supposed to write entries to Cassandra, I would like to write a test that ensure that sends an event to the read-side and then check in Cassandra that the row has indeed been written. How am I supposed to access a Cassandra session within the test?

Answer (score 2):

I do it following way:

```
class MyProcessorSpec extends AsyncWordSpec with BeforeAndAfterAll with Matchers {

  private val server = ServiceTest.startServer(ServiceTest.defaultSetup.withCassandra(true)) { ctx =>
    new MyApplication(ctx) {
      override def serviceLocator = NoServiceLocator

      override lazy val readSide: ReadSideTestDriver = new ReadSideTestDriver
    }
  }

  override def afterAll(): Unit = server.stop()

  private val testDriver = server.application.readSide
  private val repository = server.application.repo
  private val offset = new AtomicInteger()

  "The event processor" should {
    "create an entity" in {
      for {
        _ <- feed(createdEvent.id, createdEvent)
        entity <- repository.getEntityIdByKey(createdEvent.keys.head)
        entities <- repository.getAllEntities
      } yield {
        entity should be(Some(createdEvent.id))
        entities.length should be(1)

      }
    }
  }

  private def feed(id: MyId, event: MyEvent): Future[Done] = {
    testDriver.feed(id.underlying, event, Sequence(offset.getAndIncrement))
  }
}
```